# Print dates in Python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

If I print the dates of a column in an  MYSQL table than I see this:

```
(datetime.date(2017,5,26),)
```

But I want this:

```
2017-05-26
```

Here is my code:

```
connection=...
cursor = connection.cursor()
sqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM table "
sqlCommand = sqlQuery.format()
cursor.execute(sqlCommand)
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

I use Python.

Can someone help me?

Comment: How about using datetime `yourdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`?

Comment: It is rather `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", your_date)`

Comment: I use this: datetime.date.today()

Comment: then change it to `datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date is in `mydate`:

In Python 3.6:

```
print (f"{mydate:%Y-%m-%d}")
```

In earlier versions:

```
print (mydate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str()`:

```
>>> str(datetime.date(2017, 5, 26))
'2017-05-26'
```

It's the same as calling [`.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) on a date instance.